# Trouble comparing strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, echo, string-comparison

String is returned from php code and when compared it always give false, I tried using both '==' and '===' as well as using single and double quotes for strings, but no luck. I have included only the relevant parts here, let me know if you need more details to figure it out.
Please help me to find a solution, thanks in advance.

```
if(LOGINLIMIT <= $count) 
        { 
           $select = mysqli_query($conn,"update `wwwusers` set `userstatus` = 'Suspended' where username = '".$username."'"); 

           $stats = 'suspended'; 
         } 
        else 
        { 
           $stats = 'fail'; 
        } 
    } 

    $_SESSION['count'] = $count; 

    echo $stats.','.$count; }
```

String comparison happens here:

```
$.post("checkuser.php", {username: username, password: password, count: count, textcaptcha: textcaptcha}, function (data) {
        alert(data);
        var res = data.split(',');

        $('.count').val(res[1]);

        if (res[0] == 'fail')
        {
            flag = 1;
            $(".clserror").show();
            var username = $("#username").val('');
            var password = $("#password").val('');
            return false;
        } else if (res[0] == 'suspended')
        {
            flag = 0;
            $(".clserror2").show();
            var username = $("#username").val('');
            var password = $("#password").val('');
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Note: I'm just a programming enthusiast not a professional nor one who is familiar with jargon so am sorry if anything is wrong. This is my first post :)

Comment: Have you tried looking at what's in `data`?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Instead of `alert(data)` can you try `console.log(data, escape(data))`?

Comment: try to console what's in data

Comment: @georg It shows `fail,1 %20%0Afail%2C1`

Comment: @Pierre-LoupPagniez it was showing `fail,1`

Comment: It looks like res[0] contains a space and a newline character before `fail`. That would be why the comparison doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks @Pierre-LoupPagniez. That itself was the issue, its working :)

Comment: @Pierre-LoupPagniez please move your comment to an answer so @ heaven can mark this question answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @heaven showed us the escaped version of `res[0]`, there clearly was something wrong with it: it contained a space and a newline, which explains why the comparison to `fail` did not return `true`. Thanks @georg for thinking about escaping the variable.